# How do you call a C# function from an ASP.NET event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a function in my .cs page.  On the event onselectedindexchanged in .aspx I want to call this function.

How do I do this?

Comment: Its better to turn on design mode, go to the properties of your control, and add this event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you had the following method in your *.cs file:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
}
```

You could wrap the call in an event handler:

```
void RadioButtonList1_IndexChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

And your *.aspx code would look like:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_IndexChangedHandler"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just point this function to `onselectedindexchanged` property of the drop down list.

```
onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

Can you also explain how you added the Drodown List to the page?

Answer (score -1):

With the <%= %> tags

```
<%= Function() %>
```